How do I grow 5 liters of purple non-sulfur bacteria?
I am running experiments for a project that requires large amounts of purple non-sulfur, Cyanobacteria and nitrogen fixing bacteria. I plan on growing all the species in separate tanks. The species' I am using are rhodospirillum rubrum, anabaena, nitrosomonas, and nitrobacter. All the bacteria will be grown in separate tanks except for the nitrosomonas and nitrobacter which will be grown in the same tank. I need roughly 5 liters for each of these species.
In previous experiments where I only needed a few ml of bacteria, I used Alga-Gro® Seawater Medium which is technically used for algae growth. I doubt this will be viable for growing the bacteria up to 5 liters. Additionally, I am worried about contamination since I need relatively pure populations for my experiments. I am not sure if I can use the same growing techniques for each species and I don't how if growing this large a population can be done by just adding an agar solution.
I am new to growing bacteria in these quantities so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

This really sounds like something that your supervisor should be your first port of call. You could also look in the literature to see what others have done.
